# Deep link to call a user from Teams Tab

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, deep-linking, microsoft-graph-teams

I am creating a MS Teams Tab application that allows searching for contacts in various sources. Teams documentation provides a couple of deep links that are handled internally, for example:

- `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=foo@bar.com` should start a chat
- `https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=foo@bar.com` should start a call

However, the handling of those links is inconsistent, if the email is not associated with a Teams account.

For example, on the mobile client, the call link does not to anything at all, and on the desktop client, a confusing dialog is shown instead:

[image: There's a problem with the link]

The chat link works the other way around: it opens an empty group chat on the desktop, and on the mobile device it says "Invalid URL":

[image: Invalid URL]

This makes for a bad user experience and is rejected by Microsoft AppSource validation guidelines.

**Is there any way to detect whether the user has an account beforehand, so that I can disable the link and show a more descriptive error myself instead?**

Comment: You can call the get user Graph API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http with User Principal name. The API will return Request_ResourceNotFound error if the UPN does not exist. Please note that this API uses UPN and not the email.